# Rangy save and update selections in database

Tags: javascript, database, selection, highlight, rangy

I use Rangy.js for save my selections in Database (in serialize format)

```
var oSelection = rangy.getSelection();
var oRange = oSelection.getRangeAt(0)

$.ajax({
    url : 'save_selection.php',
    type : 'POST',
    async: false,
    data : {
        data: rangy.serializeRange(oRange, true, $("#Text")[0]),
    }
});
```

And after reload my page, I get my previous selections and i use highlight rangy module for create span with id ( id is a selection primary key in database ) and with .highlight class for style in my page.

But i have a problem, when i click on a span I will want delete my selection in my database, so i remove a span et I am aware that the DOM change then I update my datas in my database :

```
var aHighlights = {};

$(".highlight").each(function() {
    var oRange = rangy.createRange($(this)[0]);
    var iRangeId = $(this).attr("id");
    aHighlights[iRangeId] = rangy.serializeRange(oRange, true, $("#Text")[0])
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update_selection.php',
    async: false,
    data: {
        highlights: aHighlights
    }
});
```

But after reload my page i have this error :

Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setEnd' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 1.

Comment: Just by eyeballing your code I'm not seeing something that would explain the issue, but your issue is not one that lends itself to a solution by eyeballing. The problem could be with how the server processes the data you send, and it could be with how you use that data to restore the selections. Neither are shown in your question. You definitely should not use `async: false`, and `$(this)[0]` could be reduced to `this` but neither are what's causing the problem.

Comment: I use $(this)[0] because createRange parameter must be a Window object or DOM node

Comment: `this` is already a DOM node. It is the exact same DOM node as `$(this)[0]`.